# Are the words "whine" and "wine" pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

These two words sound exactly the same to me.  Are we assuming the "h" in "whine" is silent?

Comment: Good question. As a native english speaker, they sound the same to me.

Comment: yes, they are pronounced the same but one of them, you sometimes wish you mixed Water With The Wine

Comment: @ThirdNews Some do whine about that.

Comment: Hwat?! http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/what?q=what

Comment: @Kris I only whine about my wine when I'm outta wine

Comment: Speakers of certain dialects will pronounce the *h* in *whine,* but you will probably find that most people pronounce the two words identically.

Comment: related: [Is it affected to pronounce the “h” in wh- words such as “what”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32807/is-it-affected-to-pronounce-the-h-in-wh-words-such-as-what/215107#215107), [Hwat, hwere, and hwy?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84177/hwat-hwere-and-hwy/84179#84179)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common use, yes, *whine* and *wine* sound the same. That said, if you wanted to give attention to occurrences of /wh/ and carefully pronounce them as in "white," no one would object.

(And with *that* said, I can't help but think of Stewie and "Whil Wheaton.")

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the "h" in "Whine" sounds. For "whine" I make a breath sound followed by "wine", almost,  "h' wine". Exactly as in "white". 
Same with "win" and "when", I pronounce "when" almost "h'win".