# Pronunciation of Weather vs Whether

Tags: pronunciation

It seems to me that it's common to think that words "Whether" and "Weather" share the same pronunciation, simple google search produces the articles like
http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/weather-vs-whether/
that say:

> The words weather and whether have nothing in common other than their
>   **pronunciation**

On the other hand I learned from my favorite English Pronunciation Course which is called "Master Spoken English", what WH can be pronounced as HW:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOnRC1VjTMw&t=1m10s
But I heard from native speakers that it could be really odd if I start to say words like "When" with the initial H, like "Hwen", there is the whole episode of Family Guy around "cool whips" : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZmqJQ-nc_s

But, in the name of clarity, I think that it might be a good idea to say "Hwether".
I am curious how weird it would be from a native speaker point of view?

Comment: It would be a good idea to say "Hwether" if you meant the English word 'whether'. but not if you meant 'weather', because that is not the right way to say 'weather'.

Comment: There are quite a lot of homophones in the English language, and in my experience they rarely lead to confusion. Surely the words _whether_ and _weather_ are different enough in their grammatical usage and semantics to avoid confusion?

Comment: oerkelens that's a good point! I tend to agree that it's quite difficult to get to the point wherein "whether" and "weather" could be confused.

Comment: I would not be surprised if, using carefully calibrated recording instruments, one could detect a difference in pronunciation of these terms among a subset of English speakers, particularly those who are more literate and who likely learned to read using "phonics" at a young age.  But any difference is swamped by person-to-person variations and variations due to word context.

Comment: See for example http://english.stackexchange.com/a/32811/9368 on the "wine/whine merger"

Answer (score -1):

I think that what's causing the confusion is that the video linked to uses "HW" to refer to a sort of **elongated** "W" sound, which phonetically could be said to have an "H" sound in there but doesn't sound like someone actually saying "hwhere" or "hwhether", which people would tend to **read** as sounding more like "huh-where" and "huh-whether", which wasn't what the creators of the video intended at all.

I think that if you called it "a long W" then people might better understand the question.

But, to actually address the most important aspect of the question: I think you can pronounce "whether" and "weather" exactly the same as one another, with a short W sound, as that's what the majority of native English speakers do.  If you try to stretch the W out you **do** run the risk of it sounding quite forced and odd.

I'm trying to think of any words where you **do** want to use the elongated W sound, but haven't thought of any so far.